# At what height should a door knob be?

Tags: doors, doorknob

I'm installing a few new doors, and bought slab doors to save some money. I have a jig for boring the door knob holes, but I'm not sure where on the door to put the hole. Is there a standard height for door knobs?

Comment: Same height as the rest of them? :P

Answer (score 6):

According to the International Building Code, door knobs should be between 34" - 48" above the finished floor.

> ## International Building Code 2012
>
> ### Chapter 10 Means of Egress
>
> #### Section 1008 Doors, Gates and Turnstiles
>
> **1008.1.9.2 Hardware height.**
> Door handles, pulls, latches, locks and other operating devices shall be installed 34 inches (864 mm) minimum and 48 inches (1219 mm) maximum above the finished floor. Locks used only for security purposes and not used for normal operation are permitted at any height.

Comment: Ironic for an international code to use the US/Imperial system of measurement as the primary system (and the metric system as secondary) when pretty much the entire world uses the metric system as standard: https://www.indy100.com/article/systems-of-measurement-imperial-metric-world-map-measuring-height-7666466

Comment: @Max I think "International" in this case, just means "North American".  And since Canadians are so nice, they just let the US do what it wants.